# Changing Mouse cursor to arrow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flex4.5

I have a Flex application using ActionScript 3.0.

For any element in my application I want to set the mouse cursor to [image: move cursor] -- which is used specifically to indicate that a "move" or "drag" operation is allowed -- whenever the mouse hovers above the element.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the Mouse Cursor by using **"CursorManager"** class.

For change the **"Default Mouse Cursor"** to **"Custom Mouse Cursor"**.

```
import mx.managers.CursorManager;

[Bindable]
[Embed(source="assets/moveArrow.png")]
private var moveArrowIcon:Class;

private var cursorID:int;
```

To Set the custom mouse cursor.

```
cursorID = CursorManager.setCursor(moveArrowIcon);
```

Here **cursorID** is a integet variable to store the custom cursor ID for further use.(like remove or identify).

To Remove the custom mouse cursor.

```
CursorManager.removeCursor(cursorID);
```

For change the **"Default Mouse Cursor"** to **"Busy Cursor"**.

To Set the busy cursor.

```
CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
```

To Remove the busy cursor.

```
CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
```

*example:*

```
 <mx:Button label="Hello World"
        width="100"
        height="100"
        rollOver="cursorID = CursorManager.setCursor(moveArrowIcon);"
        rollOut="CursorManager.removeCursor(cursorID);" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Look in the help for CursorManager.